# 'end' expected (to close 'while' at line 3) near '<eof>'

Tags: lua

i'm completely new to Lua and i have got this error multiple times "'end' expected (to close 'while' at line 3) near ''" i have checked to find answers online and no luck so i was hoping someone could help me fix this problem, thanks alot

Here is my code :

```
print ("Welcome to the maze")

while input ~= "leave" do

    print ("What do you want to do first? Leave or inspect?")


    input = io.read()

    if input == "inspect" then
        print (" You venture towards the maze.")
    end

    if input == "leave" then
        print ("You turn around and run.")
    end
```

Comment: try adding a 'end' keyword in the end of the while loop body

Comment: "<eof>" means "end of file". So, the message means your code satisfied all the syntax rules up until that point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've never seen lua, but i think reading the error will be the solution:

> 'end' expected (to close 'while' at line 3)

So i need to put `end` to code:

```
print ("Welcome to the maze")

while input ~= "leave" do

    print ("What do you want to do first? Leave or inspect?")

    input = io.read()

    if input == "inspect" then
        print (" You venture towards the maze.")
    end

    if input == "leave" then
        print ("You turn around and run.")
    end

end
```

Comment: Is that really all i needed to do? Ive spend about 4 hours messing around with code... Thanks alot bud. I really appreciate it.

Comment: i hope it's just this, please give me a feedback, otherwise i can also try me in lua ;)

Comment: no problem - if you don't min you can flag my answer as solution :)

Comment: How do i do that? I'm very new to this site also.

Comment: Ah thats good to hear, am i able to personal message you as a i have a new error?

Comment: i don't think that's possible in SO - just post your problems in SO and the community will help you